# Concatenating Int + ' ' in a For loop produces a long number

Tags: c#

The following code results in 32333435363738394041. Can anyone please explain?

```
for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
{
    Console.Write(x + ' ');
}
```

Comment: Use `Console.Write(x + " ");`.

Comment: You're adding the value of the `char` ' ' (Space) to the value of `x` and outputting the resulting integer to the Console. Space has a [char value](http://www.asciitable.com/) of 32.

Comment: Without going into *implicit operators* and the built in types, you probably should just use interpolation `Console.Write($"{x} ");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `' '` is a char, not a string. To be precise, `' '` represents the space character. This character has the ASCII Code 32. Chars are numbers, so they can be used for normal calculating.
`x + ' '` can be read as `x + 32`.
Since x is integer, the `Console.Write(int)` function is called.
When `x` is `0`, `Console.Write(0+32)` is called and `32` is printed on the screen.
For `x=1` then `33`is printed directly next to `32`.
So in the end, this results in `32333435363738394041`

Answer (score 4):

Your code is adding an `int` to a `char`. Therefore, the *numeric* value of the char (AKA, ASCII code) is what's used by the `+` operator here. Why? Because the char is implicitly converted to `int`. So, the operator combines that value with the value of `x`, and the result is written to the Console.

The value of `x` starts with zero. Add that to the numeric value of the space character `' '` (which is [32 in decimal](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0020/index.htm)), and you get 32, then 33, 34, and so on.

Use a string instead:

```
Console.Write(x + " ");
```

---

Note that if you're not doing this for learning purposes, there are easier ways to achieve the same result. For example, you may replace the entire loop with something like:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", Enumerable.Range(0, 10)));
```

Comment: I was asking explanation not a solution. Thank you.

Comment: @jks Um, I think I did explain exactly why you're getting this result and then explained what you should do instead. Perhaps, other answers explained it better. In the end, I'm happy you got what you were looking for anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are adding the ascii value of `' '` to `x`. If you want to add a space between them you need to use `.ToString()` on `x`. Like this

```
for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
 {
    Console.Write(x.ToString() + ' ');
 }
```

Comment: I was asking explanation not a solution. Thank you.